# Want to customize the edit form(EditVideoSet.aspx) for Video content type on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've a requirement where I need to edit and customize the edit(EditVideoSet.aspx) form for video content type. Please suggest how we can achieve the same. Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: EditVideoSet.aspx is not directly customizable. What is your specific requirement ?